# Is it possible to write to a QBuffer that's currently being read?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm writing a PyQt5 application, but I think this question is valid for PySide2 and Qt as well. I'm trying to write sound data (sinuosids) to a buffer, then play it on a seamless loop. However, there is always a break when I get to the end of the buffer and seek back to the beginning.

I think I want to continuously read and write to the same buffer, is this possible?

Below is a minimal version of my code:

```
import struct
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer, QByteArray, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudio, QAudioFormat, QAudioOutput

sample_rate = 44100
sample_size = 16
frequency = 1000
volume = 3276


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        format = QAudioFormat()
        format.setChannelCount(1)
        format.setSampleRate(sample_rate)
        format.setSampleSize(sample_size)
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.SignedInt)

        self.output = QAudioOutput(format, self)
        self.output.stateChanged.connect(self.replay)

        self.buffer = QBuffer()
        self.buffer.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        self.createData()
        self.buffer.seek(0)
        self.output.start(self.buffer)

    def createData(self):
        print("writing")
        data = QByteArray()
        for i in range(round(1 * sample_rate)):
            t = i / sample_rate
            value = int(volume * sin(2 * pi * frequency * t))
            data.append(struct.pack("<h", value))
        self.buffer.write(data)

    def replay(self):
        print("replaying", self.output.state(), QAudio.IdleState)
        if self.output.state() == QAudio.IdleState:
            self.buffer.seek(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: buffer maintains a position, how can that work?

Comment: @Thomas `self.buffer.seek(0)` rewinds it when the audio output runs out of audio samples.

Comment: @NikosC. I understood " continuously read and write" to mean more or less concurrently. then reading and writing to the same buffer would interfere with each other.

Comment: @Thomas Correct. The question was whether doing something like that would solve the gap in each loop.

Comment: @NikosC. actually, that wasn't the question ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you've slightly misunderstood how QAudioOutput (and audio device objects in general) behaves, reads and plays audio data.

When you `play()` a QIODevice, the QAudioOutput instance reads a chunk of data according to the audio device buffer setting (but it's *not* always the same as `bufferSize()`) and "sends" it to the hardware device which actually plays it: reading data and "playing" are asynchronous. What `play()` does is to call QIODevice.readData(maxLen), where maxLen is some data length the audio device needs in order to ensure that the audio buffer is continuously filled, otherwise you'll get a buffer underrun, meaning that the device is trying to play but has no data to do it.

In your case it also means that at a certain point the audio device could request some data to the data buffer *over* its length, so you'll need to add more data to return.

Also, if you wait for the stateChanged signal, it means that there is no more data to read from the data buffer (which is *not* the audio device buffer); at this point, QAudioDevice stops the audio device and clears its buffer, so if you "replay", you will obviously hear a gap, as the device is being "restarted".

If you want to play some data in loop, you will need to implement your own QIODevice, as it has to continuously feed the audio device once it's reached its end.
Please note that this is a minimal example, you might want to further implement writing to the data buffer (and update its seek position)

```
class AudioBuffer(QIODevice):
    def __init__(self):
        QIODevice.__init__(self)
        self.bytePos = 0
        self.data = QByteArray()
        for i in range(round(1 * sample_rate)):
            t = i / sample_rate
            value = int(volume * sin(2 * pi * frequency * t))
            self.data.append(struct.pack("<h", value))

    def seek(self, pos):
        self.bytePos = pos
        return True

    def readData(self, maxLen):
        data = self.data[self.bytePos:self.bytePos + maxLen]
        if len(data) < maxLen:
            # we've reached the end of the data, restart from 0
            # so the wave is continuing from its beginning
            self.bytePos = maxLen - len(data)
            data += self.data[:self.bytePos]
        else:
            self.bytePos += maxLen
        return data.data()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.playButton = QPushButton('Play')
        self.playButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.playButton.toggled.connect(self.togglePlay)
        layout.addWidget(self.playButton)

        format = QAudioFormat()
        format.setChannelCount(1)
        format.setSampleRate(sample_rate)
        format.setSampleSize(sample_size)
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.SignedInt)

        self.output = QAudioOutput(format, self)
        self.output.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)

        self.buffer = AudioBuffer()
        self.buffer.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def togglePlay(self, state):
        self.buffer.seek(0)
        if state:
            self.output.start(self.buffer)
        else:
            self.output.reset()

    def stateChanged(self, state):
        self.playButton.blockSignals(True)
        self.playButton.setChecked(state == QAudio.ActiveState)
        self.playButton.blockSignals(False)
```

That said, I've played a bit with QAudioDevice and I'm afraid it's not very reliable, at least under PyQt/PySide. While it works fine for small examples and simple cases, it becomes unreliable if you need to do something else that require some processing while playing audio (for example complex widget/QGraphics paintings), and using QThreads won't help you as you would think: for example, under MacOS you cannot `moveToThread()` a QAudioOutput.
I strongly suggest you to use PyAudio, which has classes that behave in a similar way as QAudioOutput but can work in a different thread. Obviously, if you still need continuous playing, the "readData" issue remains the same, as you'll need some data object that can cycle itself.

PS: The title of this question is a bit off the topic at hand, you might think about changing it. Btw, the answer is no, as reading and writing of a IODevice cannot be concurring: reading should "lock" from writing (but not from further reading) and viceversa, and both operations internally move the seek `pos` of the IODevice, but since you're not dealing with threads that's not the point at all, also because in your example you've already finished writing data to the buffer before even starting to read from it, and you don't write anything after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have PyQt set up to test it myself, but try the following:

Use the [QAudioOutput::notify()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html#notify) signal. Calculate the duration of the buffer's audio in milliseconds. Use that as the interval with `setNotifyInterval()`. Connect `notify` instead of `stateChanged` to your `replay` method. Do not check for `QAudio.IdleState`, just rewind the buffer.

Comment: This will work only in the situation for which the buffer exactly contains a full sine wave cycle (or multiple complete cycles) and it also matches the audio buffer the audio device usually requests. As soon as you change the frequency to a different value (excluding harmonic multiples or divisions) you'll have issues with the buffer being restarted outside the 0 y-point of the sine function, also due to the fact that the notify signal is not always precise.